# htop shows more kthr than Tasks

Tags: htop

If htop shows more "kthr" than Tasks for me, how to interpret that? Shouldn't Tasks include all kernel threads, meaning it should always be Tasks >= kthr?

Ubuntu 18.04.5, htop 2.1.0

Comment: Maybe provide details about the version of the kernel and the version of `htop`.

Comment: Version details are now specified

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re expecting. All cars (on the highway) contain people, so does that mean that the number of cars is ≥ the number of people? No, it means cars ≤ people.

Comment: If I understand correctly, task can be either a kernel thread or a user thread. That means that kernel threads set is a subset of all tasks. My system shows more kernel threads than tasks, contradicting my understanding.

Comment: @Konstantin
Based on the example from above task a like the cars in the example.
Tasks can contain 1 ... * threads. 
These can be either kernel or user threads.
So as long as you have threads >= task everything is ok.
Otherwise something very bad happened.